# Print the structure of a Django project

Tags: django

Is there a command line or python function that prints the directory structure of my Django project?  I'm brand new to Django and I've seen this in several tutorials but I don't know how to print it:

```
   api/
    manage.py
    api/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    music/
        migrations/
            __init__.py
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
    venv/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just type in `tree` in the terminal in your Django project directory and it *will* display you the directory structure.